# C# Win32: Window will not display OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl

Using the Tao Framework, C# bindings for OpenGL/WGL/WinAPI, I am trying to make a blank WinAPI window display OpenGL graphics. This code seems to not work. The window opens, but nothing draws. Most of the OpenGL/GDI code was mirrored from Tao's ***SimpleOpenGLControl*** UserControl.
[Tao & Custom Win32 Wrappers](https://pastebin.com/2cFSmbyh)

```
public static string Hello = "Hello";
    public static string AppName = "DrawHello Program";
    public static string ClassName = "DrawHelloClass";

    public static int screenx = 250;
    public static int screeny = 250;
    public static int width = 640;
    public static int height = 480;

    public static IntPtr hWnd;
    public static IntPtr renderingContext = IntPtr.Zero;
    public static IntPtr deviceContext = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static byte accumBits = 0;                                         // Accumulation buffer bits
    public static byte colorBits = 32;                                        // Color buffer bits
    public static byte depthBits = 16;                                        // Depth buffer bits
    public static byte stencilBits = 0;                                       // Stencil buffer bits

    public static int logScaleX = 96;                                         // DPI Resolution in X dir
    public static int logScaleY = 96;

    public static void redraw()
    {
        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glVertex3f(0.5F, 0.5F, 0.5F); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5F, 0.5F, 0.5F);
        Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5F, -0.5F, 0.5F); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5F, -0.5F, 0.5F);

        Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5F, -0.5F, -0.5F); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5F, 0.5F, -0.5F);
        Gl.glVertex3f(0.5F, 0.5F, -0.5F); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5F, -0.5F, -0.5F);

        Gl.glVertex3f(0.5F, 0.5F, 0.5F); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5F, 0.5F, -0.5F);
        Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5F, 0.5F, -0.5F); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5F, 0.5F, 0.5F);

        Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5F, -0.5F, -0.5F); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5F, -0.5F, -0.5F);
        Gl.glVertex3f(0.5F, -0.5F, 0.5F); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5F, -0.5F, 0.5F);

        Gl.glVertex3f(0.5F, 0.5F, 0.5F); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5F, -0.5F, 0.5F);
        Gl.glVertex3f(0.5F, -0.5F, -0.5F); Gl.glVertex3f(0.5F, 0.5F, -0.5F);

        Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5F, -0.5F, -0.5F); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5F, -0.5F, 0.5F);
        Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5F, 0.5F, 0.5F); Gl.glVertex3f(-0.5F, 0.5F, -0.5F);
        Gl.glEnd();
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Win32.MSG Msg = new Win32.MSG();
        int rv;
        if (Program.RegisterClass() == 0)
            return;
        if (Program.Create() == 0)
            return;
        // Main message loop:
        while ((rv = Win32.GetMessage(out Msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0)) > 0)
        {
            Win32.TranslateMessage(ref Msg);
            Win32.DispatchMessage(ref Msg);
        }
    }
    private static int RegisterClass()
    {
        Win32.WNDCLASSEX wcex = new Win32.WNDCLASSEX();
        wcex.style = Win32.ClassStyles.DoubleClicks;
        wcex.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(wcex);
        wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
        wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wcex.hIcon = Win32.LoadIcon(IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)Win32.IDI_APPLICATION);
        wcex.hCursor = Win32.LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, (int)Win32.IDC_ARROW);
        wcex.hIconSm = IntPtr.Zero;
        wcex.hbrBackground = (IntPtr)(10);
        wcex.lpszMenuName = null;
        wcex.lpszClassName = ClassName;
        if (Win32.RegisterClassEx(ref wcex) == 0)
        {
            Win32.MessageBox(IntPtr.Zero, "RegisterClassEx failed", AppName,
                (int)(Win32.MB_OK | Win32.MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | Win32.MB_SETFOREGROUND));
            return (0);
        }
        return (1);
    }
    private static int Create()
    {
        hWnd = Win32.CreateWindowEx(0, ClassName, AppName, Win32.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | Win32.WS_VISIBLE,
            screenx, screeny, width, height, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        InitializeContexts();
        if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            return (1);
        Win32.MessageBox(IntPtr.Zero, "CreateWindow failed", AppName,
            (int)(Win32.MB_OK | Win32.MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | Win32.MB_SETFOREGROUND));
        return (0);
    }
    private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
            case Win32.WM_PAINT:
                {
                    IntPtr hDC;
                    Win32.PAINTSTRUCT ps = new Win32.PAINTSTRUCT();
                    hDC = Win32.BeginPaint(hWnd, out ps);
                    redraw();
                    Gdi.SwapBuffersFast(deviceContext);
                    Win32.EndPaint(hWnd, ref ps);
                    return IntPtr.Zero;
                }
            case Win32.WM_DESTROY:
                DestroyContexts();
                Win32.PostQuitMessage(0);
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            //case Win32.WM_CREATE:
            //    return IntPtr.Zero;
            default:
                return (Win32.DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam));
        }
    }
    public static void MakeCurrent()
    {
        Wgl.wglMakeCurrent(deviceContext, renderingContext);
    }
    public static void InitializeContexts()
    {
        int pixelFormat;

        Gdi.PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = new Gdi.PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR();// The pixel format descriptor
        pfd.nSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(pfd);                        // Size of the pixel format descriptor
        pfd.nVersion = 1;                                               // Version number (always 1)
        pfd.dwFlags = Gdi.PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |                          // Format must support windowed mode
                    Gdi.PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |                            // Format must support OpenGL
                    Gdi.PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;                               // Must support double buffering
        pfd.iPixelType = (byte)Gdi.PFD_TYPE_RGBA;                      // Request an RGBA format
        pfd.cColorBits = (byte)colorBits;                              // Select our color depth
        pfd.cRedBits = 0;                                               // Individual color bits ignored
        pfd.cRedShift = 0;
        pfd.cGreenBits = 0;
        pfd.cGreenShift = 0;
        pfd.cBlueBits = 0;
        pfd.cBlueShift = 0;
        pfd.cAlphaBits = 0;                                             // No alpha buffer
        pfd.cAlphaShift = 0;                                            // Alpha shift bit ignored
        pfd.cAccumBits = accumBits;                                     // Accumulation buffer
        pfd.cAccumRedBits = 0;                                          // Individual accumulation bits ignored
        pfd.cAccumGreenBits = 0;
        pfd.cAccumBlueBits = 0;
        pfd.cAccumAlphaBits = 0;
        pfd.cDepthBits = depthBits;                                     // Z-buffer (depth buffer)
        pfd.cStencilBits = stencilBits;                                 // No stencil buffer
        pfd.cAuxBuffers = 0;                                            // No auxiliary buffer
        pfd.iLayerType = (byte)Gdi.PFD_MAIN_PLANE;                     // Main drawing layer
        pfd.bReserved = 0;                                              // Reserved
        pfd.dwLayerMask = 0;                                            // Layer masks ignored
        pfd.dwVisibleMask = 0;
        pfd.dwDamageMask = 0;

        deviceContext = User.GetDC(hWnd);
        pixelFormat = Gdi.ChoosePixelFormat(deviceContext, ref pfd);
        logScaleX = Gdi.GetDeviceCaps(deviceContext, (int)Gdi.DevCaps.LOGPIXELSX);
        logScaleY = Gdi.GetDeviceCaps(deviceContext, (int)Gdi.DevCaps.LOGPIXELSY);
        renderingContext = Wgl.wglCreateContext(deviceContext);
        MakeCurrent();
        Kernel.SetProcessWorkingSetSize(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1);
    }
    public static void DestroyContexts()
    {
        Wgl.wglMakeCurrent(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        Wgl.wglDeleteContext(renderingContext);
        User.ReleaseDC(hWnd, deviceContext);
        renderingContext = IntPtr.Zero;
        deviceContext = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: If you are attempting to use OpenGL higher than 1.1 you need to create an OpenGL 1.1 window, declare a new OpenGL 3.x window from there and then close the first window while opening the second. I am unsure about the library you are using or it's compatibility with more modern frameworks, it could be that it was designed for earlier .NET versions and is using deprecated functions. Do they have a github page?

Comment: The library is very old, but it still works. It has no official github page, but here is one with the source: https://github.com/mono/tao

Comment: oh wow that is old, OGL 2.1. TBH I would be abandoning that library and either create my own or look at any others as it is so old.

Maybe take a look at this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265903/Using-OpenGL-in-a-WPF-Application

The one above is ~9 years old and is OGL 4.2